# How to return values from a different ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

I am trying to do this with one View, perhaps this is not the best way?

I have a form that is data driven; the questions all come from a Questions table but the answers populate a Response table. here is the View;

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
    @model Template.Models.Question

 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "View question";
   var qtype = Model.QuestionTypeId;
   ViewBag.Number = Model.Id - 7;
   Html.BeginForm("ViewQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }); 
}

<h4>Question #@ViewBag.Number</h4>
<hr />
<h1> @Model.Question1</h1>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>

    @switch (qtype)
    {
        case 1:
            // Textbox
            @Html.TextArea("Answer", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "4", col = "5" });<br /><br />
            break;
        case 2:
            // Dropdown
            <select class="form-control" id="Answer">
            @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
             {
                 <option value="@item.QuestionOption1">@item.QuestionOption1</option>

             }
             </select><br /><br />
             break;
        case 3:
             //  Checkbox
                 <div class="checkbox">
                 @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
                  {
                   <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />  @item.QuestionOption1 <br />
                  }
                 </div><br /><br />
                 break;
        case 4:
             //      Radio buttons
             foreach (var item in Model.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
             {
              <div class="radio">
               <label>
               <input type="radio" name="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />
               @item.QuestionOption1
               </label>
               </div>
             }<br /><br />
            break;
    }

</div>
<input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" value="@Model.Id" />
<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@User.Identity.GetUserId()" />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Answer" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my ViewModel;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Template.Models
{
public class GetQuestionViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public string Question1 { get; set; }

    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> LinkedTo { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> Options { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> QuestionRanking { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please answer the question before submitting")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public System.DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> Duplicate { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Questions { get; set; }

    public object SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
}
}
```

I cannot get the GetQuestionViewModel to work at all and have resorted to the .emdx version of the Question Model to populate the page, but my task is a) display each user's answers on the page, and b) display the questions on the PageNumber field as any number of questions can be displayed on a single screen.

Here is my controller but as you can see more is commented out than work!

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Template.Models;

namespace Template.Controllers
{
public class QuestionController : Controller
{
    private WebTemplateEntities db = new WebTemplateEntities();

    // GET: /Questions/ViewQuestion/5
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0 || id > 12)
        {
            id = 8;
        }
        var question = db.Questions.Find(id);
        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(question);
    }

    //        [Route("Questions/{page?}")]
    //public ActionResult ViewQuestion(GetQuestionViewModel model, int? id)
    //{
    //    if (id == null || id == 0 || id > 12)
    //    {
    //        //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    //        id = 8;
    //        //return RedirectToAction("/ViewQuestion/" + id);
    //    }

    //    var q = db.Questions.Find(id);
    //    var pageId = q.PageNumber;

    //    var questions = from q in db.Questions
    //                    where q.PageNumber == pageId
    //                    orderby q.QuestionRanking
    //                    select q;
    //    return View(questions);
    // }

    // POST: /Questions/ViewQuestion/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion([Bind(Include = "QuestionId, Answer, UserId")] ResponseViewModel responseViewModel)
    {
        Response re = new Models.Response();
        re.Answer = responseViewModel.Answer;
        if (re.Answer == null)
        {
            re.Answer = "Work in progress!";
            //    re.Answer = responseViewModel.SelectedValue();
            //    re.Answer = int.Parse(SelectList["Question.QuestionOption1"]);
        }
        re.UserId = responseViewModel.UserId;
        re.QuestionId = responseViewModel.QuestionId;
        var id = responseViewModel.QuestionId;
        re.Source = "Web";
        re.Status = "New";
        re.DateStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
        db.Responses.Add(re);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ViewQuestion/" + (id + 1));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
  }
}
```

I have been working on this problem for literally days and now am just going around in circles. Any help or advice would me greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, it's bad practice to have your Question Number that is displayed in the view be based on an Id.  the Id should be completely agnostic of your implementation.  There should be a separate field that is used to store the actual question number.

Comment: Agreed. I am planning to switch this to page number when I can get that working correctly. But I am stuck on displaying the user's answers at the moment. Both are plaguing me!

Comment: Is your [Route...] working?  When you navigate to that url, does the controller method execute?

Comment: Also, the method appears to return a View(Template.Models.Question) instead of a View(Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing Entity models and ViewModels.  In your view you reference `Template.Models.Question`, which appears to be an Entity rather than a ViewModel.

The view should only reference your ViewModel, and not your Entity.  And there should be some mapping mechanism established between your Entity and your ViewModel.  Another thing I noticed is that your Entity and your ViewModel appear to reside in the same namespace in your application.  This isn't necessarily a problem, but can get confusing as ViewModels pertain to your view only and Entities pertain to your persistence layer.

Currently your code is getting a question object via this: `from q in db.Questions` which you are then passing into View(question).  So you will not actually have your ViewModel available in the view, it will be your entity model.

Change your view to:

```
@model Template.Models.GetQuestionViewModel
```

And change your controller to something like this:

```
var questions = (from q in db.Questions
                where q.PageNumber == pageId
                orderby q.QuestionRanking
                select q.ToViewModelExtensionMethod()).ToList();

return View(questions);
```

You'll have to write that extension method to perform the mapping from Template.Model.Question to Template.Model.GetQuestionViewModel.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

For info about extension methods, here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

I just use extension methods because I like the way the syntax flows.  Here's a quick example:

```
namespace Template.Models.Extensions
{
    public static class QuestionExtensions
    {
        public static GetQuestionViewModel ToViewModelExtensionMethod(this Question question)
        {
            var result = new GetQuestionViewModel();
            result.field1 = question.field1;
            // ... etc
            return result;
        }
    }   
}
```

Also, note the change above where I am now mapping the items as they are queried.

Comment: You are correct Aaron, I am confused by entities and viewmodels. Can you give me any more details or sample of what you mean by " extension method to perform the mapping" as this is the part that really confuses me?